# HTML ignores elements on list

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

my webpage sends a URL and xpath query to the server, that extract the data from the URL according to the xpath query.
it works ok, but I'm having a single problem.

when I send and xpath query to href,text it shows me a list of all the items.
but if the xpath query refers to an element and not its attribute (a instead of a/@href) i'm getting an empty list.

here is the code:

```
              $.get("/extract/validate_xpath", {url:document.getElementById('v_url').value,
              query:document.getElementById('v_query').value} ,function(data, status){
              console.log(typeof data);
              console.log(status);
              console.log(data);
              document.getElementById("v_answer").style.display="block";
              document.getElementById("v_answer").innerHTML=data;
           });
```

data is the response from the server.

I tried console.log to these test the response and the type, data is a string.

When I console.log(data) I'm getting the element list

while on the HTML im getting and empty list:

> [, , , , ,]

I tried to copy what JS console shows me but even here it's not showing.
[here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPly8.jpg)

How can I force it to print it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your Javascript code.

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html file is trying to treat these elements inside your array as an HTML element `<Element div at 0x76666j4k4j5kw/e>`. Since the browser doesn't understand that element, nothing is rendered.

If you want do just display that `string`, you have to escape the greater then and less then symbols.

```
data = data.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;');
document.getElementById("v_answer").innerHTML=data;
```

Comment: it worked just for the first element, for some reason the rest remained unchanged.

Comment: using regex or moving it to server-side using python solved it. Thank you